# Why does "writes" take "to" but "reads" not take "to"?

Tags: grammar, transitivity, particles

I hope this is the right sub, but I was wondering what the technical difference is between words such as "write", which take the particle "to" when involved with a grammatical object, and "read", which does not, in terms of both the formal categorical differences between the two words and the semantic differences which produce them.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question;  consider the sentences *I can write a book* and *I can read a book*;  and also *I can write to my child* and *I can read to my child.*  The particle 'to' can be used or omitted with both verbs.

Comment: @Hellion: True, but many people (AmE speakers ion particular, I suspect), are quite happy to omit the preposition in contexts such as *I'll write my rich uncle and ask him to send me some money*, but quite a lot of us would see that as at least *slightly* "questionable".

Comment: Descriptions of grammatical phenomena using jury-rigged terminology are far less useful than actual **examples** of the kind of sentence you are asking about. So far it's "unclear what you're asking about".

Comment: @JohnLawler The question was specific in using the simple present, a fact which everyone has chosen to ignore.

Comment: That's because the tense of the verb has nothing to do with whether it takes an infinitive complement, nor whether it uses a complementizer _t0_. If it works in present, it'll work in past, and vice versa.

Comment: @JohnLawler First you ask for more specificity, now you ask for less

Answer (score 1):

*Write* takes a direct object, the thing written (either the physical words, or the text written), and may take an indirect object with *to*, when it means "write a letter or message to be sent to somebody". Occasionally it takes both, though usually not. It can also take other prepositional phrases, with *on* for the surface, *with* for the tool or pigment, *in* for the language etc.

*Read* takes a direct object, the thing read (again, either the physical marks, or the text being read), and may take an indirect object with *to*, when it means "read something out loud to be heard by somebody".  It can also take other prepositional phrases, with *from* for the book or paper, *in* for the language etc.

These seem to me to be pretty much parallel.